# 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using simple function on Python :

```
def liste_bis(data):

Country_Name = []
Platform_Category = []
Platform = []
Country_Acronym = []

for m,n in enumerate (np.arange(np.shape(data)[0])):

    if (data["domain1"][m]=='afe'):

        Country_Name.append('France')
        Platform_Category.append('App')
        Platform.append('BDDF-HB App')
        Country_Acronym.append('FR')


    elif (data["domain1"][m]=='afer'):

        Country_Name.append('France')
        Platform_Category.append('Site')
        Platform.append('BDDF-HB Site')
        Country_Acronym.append('FR')


    elif (data["domain1"][m]=='afert'):

        Country_Name.append('France')
        Platform_Category.append('App')
        Platform.append('BDDF-BNP App')
        Country_Acronym.append('FR')


    elif (data["domain1"][m]=='aferty'):

        Country_Name.append('France')
        Platform_Category.append('Site')
        Platform.append('BDDF-BNP Site')
        Country_Acronym.append('FR')

    elif (data["domain1"][m]=='afertyu'):

        Country_Name.append('Luxembourg')
        Platform_Category.append('App')
        Platform.append('BGL-BNP App')
        Country_Acronym.append('LU')

dictionnaire = {"Country_Name":Country_Name,"Platform_Category":Platform_Category,"Platform":Platform,"Country_Acronym":Country_Acronym}

return(dictionnaire)
```

But i have some troubles.
When I execute programm, it returns me  :

```
'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'
```

But When i use this function with DataFrame with just 1 row, it works weel.
But When i have more than 1 row, it doesnt work ...

Let you show an example of dataframe that i use : 
[dataframe_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6FEn.png)

Could you helpe me please ?

Thank you

Comment: How do you expect `data["domain1"][m]=='afe'` to behave when `data["domain1"][m]` has more than one element. Should it only enter the if when all elements in `data["domain1"][m]` satisfy the condition?

Comment: Your code has bad indentation, which is critical in Python. Also, it is not complete, since you do not show how that function is called, the definition of the paramter's value, or even the import for numpy. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FlyingTeller there is just 1 element in data["domain1"][m]

Comment: Could you maybe add example of data and desired output?

Comment: @zipa ok i done

Answer (score 0):

Why it works only with a one-element result: When you have a multi-element Series, its "truth value" might be a Series of truth values, or it might be the answer to "are *all* of these values True", etc. With one row, there is no such ambiguity. So choose one of the explicit methods recommended by the error message (depending on what you are really after), and move on.

Comment: thank you for your reponse. But i have juste one element, so i dont understand error message

Comment: How many dimensions does your array `data` have? Sounds like it has three. If `m` is an integer, `data["domain1"][m]` has two dimensions less, and you're comparing all of it, i.e., **each element of it** to a string.

Comment: @alexis 
I just modified my post, you can see in image the structure of my DataFrame, thank you

Comment: That tells me nothing, the output of `np.shape(data)` would be more useful (and for godssake not as an image please!). Anyway I'm going from your description. You didn't say which code line caused the error, or give a complete error trace. If I misunderstood, please _fix your question._ We want to help but you need to help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help @alexis my english it is not good, this is why my question it is not good.

Comment: Your English is perfectly understandable, don't worry. But don't use English, use copy-paste (of the error trace, diagnostic code and output, etc.). Take a look at some similar questions with upvotes to see how to do it better.